# Beginner to Haskell type system : "Haskell non-type variable argument in constraint" Error

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, functional-programming

In an attempt to dip my toes in functional programming, I'm attempting to pick up Haskell and running into some mental issues with the type system.

Running the following code gives proper output (e.g. generates coordinates for a circle wrapped around a cylinder of radius R at angle theta):

```
coilGeneration_AngleTest housingRadius coilWidth coilDepth numEle zoffset centralAngle
     = [ (x',y',z)
       | theta <- [0,2*pi/(numEle-1)..2*pi]
       , let x = housingRadius * cos(coilWidth*cos(theta)/housingRadius)
       , let y = housingRadius * sin(coilWidth*cos(theta)/housingRadius)
       , let z = coilDepth * sin(theta)+zoffset
       , let x' = x * cos(centralAngle) - y * sin(centralAngle)
       , let y' = x * sin(centralAngle) + y * cos(centralAngle)
       ]
```

[Sample coilGeneration_AngleTest function output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MBEe.png)

However, attempting to generalize this into a function that generates an arbitrary NxM array of circles with varying overlaps in the polar and z-directions by running:

```
coilArrayGeneration_Test r nE width depth n m mu gam
     = [ (x',y',z',i,j)
       | theta <- [0,2*pi/(nE-1)..2*pi]
       , i <- [1..n]
       , j <- [1..m]
       , let a = width/2
       , let b = depth/2
       , let x = r * cos(a*cos(theta)/r)
       , let y = r * sin(a*cos(theta)/r)
       , let z = b * sin(theta)
       , let phi = (2*i-1-n)((a-mu)/r)
       , let zo = (2*j-1-m)(b-gam)
       , let x' = x * cos(phi) - y * sin(phi)
       , let y' = x * sin(phi) + y * cos(phi)
       , let z' = z + zo
       ]
```

gives the following error:

```
Build profile: -w ghc-9.2.5 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - Haskell-0.1.0.0 (exe:Haskell) (file app/Main.hs changed)
Preprocessing executable 'Haskell' for Haskell-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'Haskell' for Haskell-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, /Users/zack/Desktop/Udemy/Haskell/dist-newstyle/build/aarch64-osx/ghc-9.2.5/Haskell-0.1.0.0/x/Haskell/build/Haskell/Haskell-tmp/Main.o )

app/Main.hs:66:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (c -> c)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        coilArrayGeneration_Test :: forall {c}.
                                    (Floating c, Num (c -> c), Enum c, Enum (c -> c)) =>
                                    c
                                    -> c
                                    -> c
                                    -> c
                                    -> (c -> c)
                                    -> (c -> c)
                                    -> c
                                    -> c
                                    -> [(c, c, c, c -> c, c -> c)]
   |
66 | coilArrayGeneration_Test r nE width depth n m mu gam = [(x',y',z',i,j)|theta <- [0,2*pi/(nE-1)..2*pi],....
```

[Failure Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0y5O.png)

After googling for a while, it seemed that my function had an improper type implied by the compiler but I unfortunately don't understand the idea Haskell Type Definition well enough to fix it. I attempted to define the types the way I see them, namely:

- r     -> Double
- nE    -> Int
- width -> Double
- depth -> Double
- n     -> Int
- m     -> Int
- mu    -> Double
- gam   -> Double
- x' -> Double
- y' -> Double
- z' -> Double
- I  -> Int
- j  -> Int

Getting:

```
coilArrayGeneration_Test :: (Floating a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a -> a -> b -> b -> a -> a -> [(a,a,a,b,b)]
coilArrayGeneration_Test r nE width depth n m mu gam
      = [ (x',y',z',i,j)
        | theta <- [0,2*pi/(nE-1)..2*pi]
        , i <- [1..n]
        , j <- [1..m]
        , let a = width/2
        , let b = depth/2
        , let x = r * cos(a*cos(theta)/r)
        , let y = r * sin(a*cos(theta)/r)
        , let z = b * sin(theta)
        , let phi = (2*i-1-n)((a-mu)/r)
        , let zo = (2*j-1-m)(b-gam)
        , let x' = x * cos(phi) - y * sin(phi)
        , let y' = x * sin(phi) + y * cos(phi)
        , let z' = z + zo
        ]
```

But this threw a whole host of errors:

[Errors after Type Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5vrl.jpg)

Which clearly means I don't know what I'm doing and mucked up the type declarations somehow.

Can anyone steer me the right way?

Comment: When learning Haskell, I'd recommend the following: 1) when writing a (function) definition, always start from writing its intended type, 2) in your first exercises, don't use types which are more general than you really need. It's probably OK to initially use `f :: Int -> Int` even when it could be generalized to `f :: Num a => a -> a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you see a compiler error involving something like `Num (c -> c)`, it never has anything to do with `-XFlexibleContexts` or with incorrect inferred types. It simply means you attempted to use something as a function which is not a function.

“Use as a function” entails simply that you have some expression of the form `f x`, where `f` and `x` can be arbitrary subexpressions. This includes in particular also expressions like `(1+2)(3+4)`, which is the same as

```
     let f = 1 + 2
         x = 3 + 4
     in f x
```

Presumably you meant to express multiplication by the juxtaposition. Well, use the multiplication operator then! I.e. `(1+2)*(3+4)`.

Your code has also another problem: you trying to use the index variables in real-valued expression. Unlike the missing multiplication operators, this is fairly sensible, but Haskell doesn't allow this either. You need to explicitly wrap the integrals in `fromIntegral`.

```
coilArrayGeneration_Test r nE width depth n m μ γ
      = [ (x',y',z',i,j)
        | ϑ <- [0, 2*pi/fromIntegral(nE-1) .. 2*pi]
        , i <- [1..n]
        , j <- [1..m]
        , let a = width/2
              b = depth/2
              x = r * cos(a*cos ϑ/r)
              y = r * sin(a*cos ϑ/r)
              z = b * sin ϑ
              φ = fromIntegral(2*i-1-n) * ((a-μ)/r)
              z₀ = fromIntegral(2*j-1-m) * (b-γ)
              x' = x * cos φ - y * sin φ
              y' = x * sin φ + y * cos φ
              z' = z + z₀
        ]
```

I would strongly recommend you refactor this a bit, both code and types. 5-tuples are very obscure, you should at least wrap `x,y,z` in a suitable vector type.

Comment: That makes so much sense now that I can see it.  So converting to proper types using the fromX functions was the big thing I was missing.

I appreciate the help!!

Comment: @ztth222 Many languages automatically convert numeric types, e.g. summing an integer and a double causes the integer to be promoted to double. Haskell instead never does that, and `fromIntegral` and the like must be explicitly used in the code. Overall, I find Haskell a bit less convenient for numeric code but often much safer: the infamous example `1/2*x` is equivalent to _zero_ in C but is instead equivalent to `0.5*x` in Haskell.

Comment: @chi to be honest, this example is mostly one of how C is unsafe, and it's a bit strange that so many languages followed it in this regard. Python 3 doesn't have the problem: its `/` operator is always fractional like in Haskell, but it still allows integer arguments. This works perfectly satisfying in practice. What makes it annoying in Haskell is that `fromInteger` is such an unwieldy mouthful. [`from`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witch-1.1.6.0/docs/Witch.html#v:from) is an alternative that I would quite like to see becoming widely adapted.

Comment: ...though, it looks like it deliberately only converts `Int32` to `Double`, for `Int` it requires `tryFrom`. Which actually makes sense too, but also incurs nuisance of its own.

Comment: @leftaroundabout IMO, `Int` to `Double` should just work without having to jump more hoops. I agree on `fromIntegral` being too long, but to be honest I never had to use it too much (perhaps because I rarely deal with floating point data). `from` could be a better option. Anyway, one can always have a non-exported `frI = fromIntegral` shortcut definition in the modules that need frequent conversions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I just realized that probably `from` and `tryFrom` are meant to perform exact, lossless conversions only. If that's the goal, it makes sense, but I would rather use a different class to convert to floating point. Forbidding the conversion of a small number like `16777216` to float because it's "too large" like `tryFloat` does, when the float type supports up to `2^128` (albeit in a lossy way), is too radical for many applications.